# Sublime Doctype HTML Snippet

Tags: sublimetext, code-snippets

Is there a way that this here below ↓↓↓ can be inserted as a snippet?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>

</body>

</html>
```

I tried using Preferences -> Key Bindings - User but quotation marks really matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a new snippet via `Tools -> New Snippet...`

[image]

You can [read more about creating and using snippets here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html).

FYI, the [HTML5 doctype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Introduction_to_HTML5) is probably more appropriate and much easier to remember, simply:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Additional info about format and more can be found here docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html

Comment: @Cecil That sounds like you replaced the entire snippet with your markup, which is not correct. You need to put your snippet content between `<snippet><content><!CDATA[ HERE ]]</content></snippet>` when you begin creating it.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I was just trying to achieve the same feature as this shows. http://bryansiegel.com/2011/07/how-to-make-a-html-skeleton-snippet-in-textmate/

Answer (score 5):

Just to spell it out, so you don't need to follow links:

After selecting **`Tools -> New Snippet...`**, modify its content to the following:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>$0</title>

</head>
<body>

</body>

</html>
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>newpage</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

The `$0` between the `<title>` tags indicates that your cursor will end up here after triggering the snippet. If you'd like to have multiple insertion points that you can <kbd>Tab</kbd> between them, use `$1` as the first, `$2` as the second, etc., using `$0` as the final spot.

Save the snippet in your `Packages/User` directory (it *should* be the default when you hit save) as `newpage.sublime-snippet`. To test it, open a new file, set the syntax to HTML, type ***`newpage`***, and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and you should be all set.