# Default page setup like dreamweaver in Sublime text 2?

Tags: php, html, css, sublimetext2, dreamweaver

I really like dreamweaver and am trying to switch to sublime text. The only thing missing in sublime text is that when you create a new document you have to fill in all the page info (`<!doctype html>, <html>, <head>`) In dreamweaver it did this for you. Is there a way to do this in Sublime text? Thanks

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987632/sublime-doctype-html-snippet/24987648#24987648) might help you.

Comment: This is not a way you should accept the answer! The answer you accepted is even not a complete answer, for me it looks like your profile only!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plugins for this. Such as SublimeTmpl

Answer (score 3):

What you need is the [SublimeTmpl](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeTmpl) which does exactly that. Install it using the [Package Manager](https://sublime.wbond.net/). Then press `CTRL+SHIFT+P` and type "Install" and hit `ENTER`.

Then, search for `SublimeTmpl`. Finally, create a new file and press `CTRL+ALT+H` and you should get something like this:

[image]

Of course, this can work for many other types of files (html, js, css, php, python, ruby, etc.) and you'd have to hit their required keystroke for that.

Here are the default key bindings:

> ctrl+alt+h html
>
> ctrl+alt+j javascript
>
> ctrl+alt+c css
>
> ctrl+alt+p php
>
> ctrl+alt+r ruby
>
> ctrl+alt+shift+p python

Comment: is there a way where all documents will open like a html file as default?

Comment: @user3765605 No, sorry. You'll just have to remember the key-strokes.